Why I am getting this error in openlayers? TileLayer.js:636 Uncaught TypeError: T[g] is not iterable
Hi I am new to openlayers and I am quite confused why I am getting this error.
This is how I build my openlayers.

const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();

const defaultInteractions = ol.interaction.defaults.defaults({
    pinchRotate: false,
});

const tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    preload: 2,
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: `http://localhost:8082/storage/tiles/${seed}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`,
        wrapX: false,
    }),
});

const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
});

const map = new ol.Map({
    target: "map",
    layers: [tileLayer, vectorLayer],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 4,
        minZoom: 3,
        maxZoom: 6,
        multiWorld: true,
        extent: undefined,
    }),
    interactions: defaultInteractions,
});


map.getView().on("change:resolution", function () {
    const zoom = map.getView().getZoom();
    console.log("Zoom level changed to:", zoom);
});


What I am trying to do here is create an infinite map, but when I try to pan around to a certain coordinates the tiles will just disappear and it will give me this error.

See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/16038   If you are using 10.0.0 upgrade to 10.1.0

@Mike thank you for the help, I was using CDN when I got this issue. Then I install OL to my app then everything works.
